# Javascript copy to clipboard only works if I have a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard, breakpoints

I have this function that is called when I push a button:

```
function copyCredentials(elementId) {
  var el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
  el.style.position = 'absolute';
  el.style.left = '-9999px';
  document.body.appendChild(el);

  el.value = document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML;

  var selected = document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0
          ? document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
          : false;
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  if (selected) {
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    document.getSelection().addRange(selected);
  }
}
```

This code only works if I put a breakpoint. In normal usage it doesn't copy a thing...
What's the catch here?

Comment: Hi @Jorge Raimundo, have you managed to solve this? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Hi, @SergеуIsupov, I found a workaround below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53766286/1557550)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a different approach. Instead of creating a new element, I'm grabbing the text from the original element (please note that it is the content a `<code>` tag inside a `<pre>` tag):

```
function copyCredentials(elementId) {
  var range;
  var selection;
  var el = document.getElementById(elementId);

  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(el);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
  document.execCommand('copy');
  if (selection) {
    selection.removeRange(range);
  }
}
```

And it works!!! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine. I didn't remove any of your code, I don't know what you're trying to do but you probably need it for something. It's important to emphasize that clipboard code has to run after user takes an action (e.g button click), this is a measure to avoid trolling/improve security.

```js
function copyCredentials(elementId) {
  var el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
  el.style.position = 'absolute';
  el.style.left = '-9999px';
  document.body.appendChild(el);

  // note that you need to get .value instead
  // of .innerHTML if target is input type
  el.value = document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML;

  var selected = document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0
          ? document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
          : false;
           
  el.select();
  // returns boolean
  var successfulCopy = document.execCommand('copy');
  
  if (!successfulCopy) {
    alert('Something went wrong or no browser support!').
    return;
  }

  if (selected) {
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    document.getSelection().addRange(selected);
  }
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  copyCredentials('text');
});
```

```html
<b>Text to paste:</b>
<div id="text">
  Hello World
</div>

<br />
<br />

<button id="button">Copy</button> <br />

<div>
  <b>Paste here:</b> <br />
  <textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some obscure reason it doesn't work on my application unless I put a breakpoint on the code...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this function for copying value from `textarea`?

```js
function copyCredentials(elementId) {
  const value = document.getElementById('textarea_id').value;
  const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', value);
  document.body.appendChild(hiddenInput);
  hiddenInput.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(hiddenInput);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea_id"></textarea>

<button onclick="copyCredentials()">CLICK</button>
```

Ps. I removed `rangeCounts` because I'm not sure why you need them there. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Thanks, @CodeMeNatalie, but unfortunately that has the same behaviour...
The `rangeCounts` were to see if there was something already selected by the user, store it and put it back in the end.